# Evaluating $\int \arcsin(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})\,dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I found this integral here: https://www.12000.org/my_notes/ten_hard_integrals/index.htm

Sites like https://www.integral-calculator.com/, which I often find very helpful, did not successfully calculate the integral.

I have found a potential answer, that seems to be correct.

Using the formula

$$\int f(x)\,dx=x \cdot f(x)-\left[{\int f^{-1}(y)\,dy}\right]_{y=f(x)},$$

I calculated :

$$\int \arcsin(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})\,dx = x \cdot \arcsin(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})+\frac{3}{8}\arcsin(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})+\frac{1}{8}\sqrt{\sqrt{x(x+1)}-x}\cdot[(1+2\sqrt{2})\sqrt{x+1}-(1-2\sqrt{2})\sqrt{x}]$$

My question is: How else could I integrate this function? Is there an easier way?
I tried to substitute $x=tan(u)^2$ but it seems that the resulting integral is an extremely long combination of sines and cosines.

Thank you for your help

**Additional notes on my reasoning:**

The inverse function of $\arcsin(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})$ is $\left(\frac{\sin^2 x-1}{2\sin x}\right)^2$

Integrating this function can be done by expanding the square :

$$\int \left(\frac{\sin^2 y-1}{2\sin y}\right)^2 dy=\int \frac{1}{4}(\sin^2 y-2+\csc^2 y)\,dy$$

After having calculated that integral, we replace y by $\arcsin(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})$. After some simplification work, I get the result mentioned above.

Comment: Well on the website it says mathematica can integrate it "correctly", so I suppose you can check if the expression you got is equivalent with it.

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions like arcsin you get the right font and spacing, so \arcsin x gives $\arcsin x$ compared to arcsin x giving $arcsin x$

Comment: @RossMillikan thank you

Comment: @GarethMa thank you, though what I'm looking for is another way to manually integrate this function.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add on. I am still working on this problem. I was thinking that we could build of the identities:

$$\sin(a-b) = \sin(a)cos(b) - \cos(a)\sin(b)$$
$$a-b = \arcsin(\sin(a)\cos(b) - \cos(a)\sin(b))$$.

We could find two functions that we can integrate, $a$ and $b$, where $\sin(a)\cos(b) = \sqrt{x+1}$ and $\cos(a)\sin(b) = \sqrt{x}.$ I was thinking probably letting $a$ and $b$ being some inverse trig functions and proceeding from there.